# is initialize controller load before the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, appdelegate

I need to load controller programmatically from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, but unfortunately first initialize controller load and than from the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, so is there any way to load controller first from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. 
  my code is here

```
        if UserModel.getUserSessionKey() != ""{
        let dict = [
            "access_token": UserModel.getUserToken()]
        print("dictionay",dict)
        let header = [
            "sessionkey":UserModel.getUserSessionKey()]
        ServiceWrapper.myRetailers(header,requestObject: dict) { (success, response) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                // Alert.showAlert("Alert", message: "Success")
                self.isLogIn = true
                self.createMenuView();

            }
            else{

              // Alert.showAlert("Alert", message: "Failed")

                MyRetailersViewController.deleteRetailers()
                let featured = FeaturedController()
                featured.deleteData()
                let defaults  = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                defaults.removeObjectForKey("isSaved")
                defaults.removeObjectForKey("update")
                CoreDataHelper.deleteData("OfferDetail")
                self.isLogIn = false
                self.createMenuView();

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your didFinishLaunchingwithOption method is call before but your Web service take more time to give a response. Then your initial view controller set from the storyboard.That's it

Comment: you are right, i understand that, but what is solution? i have to show viewController with respect to service response

Comment: I have post my answer might be you interested

Answer (score 0):

I would like say this not a proper solution, But Work for you.

**Seriously Call API in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is not a good idea when you have to set root view controller according to response.**

1) Create new view controller(NewviewViewController).

2) Set it to root view controller.

3) Call your service in NewviewViewController `viewWillaAppear` method (Start Loading indicator here)

4) According to response initiate your controller.

Other solution

1)remove initial controller from storyboard then call your API set Root view controller according to response.

In this case you have get a Black window until the API not call successfully.

**Be careful what's happen in case user don't have any internet connection. In second case your application open with the blank window not a next screen.**